# How to conduct complex operations using sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I am using sympy in Python 2.7. All data are complex numbers. In sympy, using `I` stand for `j`. For example, `1+2j` will be transformed to `1+2I`. But when I pick the complex data from `sympy.Matrix` to a list, the `I` still be `I`, it couldn't transformed to `j`. So, in a list, I got some results as follows:

```
[-0.00380729396990433 + (0.180207819939565 - 0.083853515413911*I)*(1.73101916117909 - 0.0151308105703527*I) + 0.00494319233978506*I, -0.00380729396990433 + (0.180207819939565 - 0.083853515413911*I)*(1.71894935222892 - 0.138744154478851*I)]
```

Python couldn't compute automatically. I want to know how to solve this problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [in the documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/evalf.html),

> You can also use the standard Python functions float(), complex() to convert SymPy expressions to regular Python numbers

```
a = [-0.00380729396990433 + (0.180207819939565 - 0.083853515413911*I)*(1.73101916117909 - 0.0151308105703527*I) + 0.00494319233978506*I, -0.00380729396990433 + (0.180207819939565 - 0.083853515413911*I)*(1.71894935222892 - 0.138744154478851*I)]
print complex(a[0])
```

This prints a tuple containing a standard Python complex number:

```
(0.306867123682-0.142935539961j)
```